# Could someone help me understand the AMS Sketch?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to use the AMS Sketch I found in MassDAL Code Bank:
http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/massdal-code-index.html

Due to the lack of documentation, I can't figure out what exactly the requested variables are in the functions. In the first one, what exactly are the buckets and depth? Are they a standard or depends on the project?